# how to create a column char with highcharts where each column has a different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I´ve a chart using highcharts, the only problem is that each column has the same column.
What should I do so each column has a different column.
Here is my code:

```
var charts = [];
$containers = $('#container1');
var datasets = [
{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49, 57]
}];
var cat = ['A', 'B'];

console.log(datasets);
$.each(datasets, function(i, dataset) {
    console.log(dataset);
    charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: $containers[i],
            type: 'column',
            marginLeft: i === 0 ? 100 : 10
        },
        title: {
            text: dataset.name,
            align: 'left',
            x: i === 0 ? 90 : 0
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: cat,
            labels: {
                enabled: i === 0
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [dataset]
    }));
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To have each column be a different color, all you have to do is set the `colorByPoint` property to `true`.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint

Alternatively you can make each column a separate series, which gives you additional levels of control.

*OTOH, in the majority of cases, having each column a separate color serves no purpose except to clutter and confuse the data, and make the user work harder cognitively to interpret the chart.*

If you want to highlight a single column for a particular reason, you can do that by adding the fillColor property to the data array:

Something like:

```
data:[2,4,5,{y:9,fillColor:'rgba(204,0,0,.75)',note:'Wow, look at this one'},4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to show more than 1 color for each column:

```
 var charts1 = [];
     var $containers1 = $('#container1');
     var datasets1 = [{
                    name: 'Dalias',
                    data: [29]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Lilas',
                    data: [1]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Tulipanes',
                    data: [15]
                }];
        $('#container1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Montos pedidos por división'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color};" />{series.name} </span>:<b>{point.y}</b>',
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series : {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            /*click: function() {
                                verDetalle("Especialidades,"+ this.series.name);
                            }*/
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            credits:{
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['División']
            },
            series: datasets1
        });
```